# StartSSL.com SSL Class2 Certificate and Postfix

Tags: ssl, postfix, ssl-certificate, openssl

currently my `Postfix 2.11` instance runs TLS on a `GoDaddy SSL Certificate` but as i would like to be able to access my server from smtp.example.com as well as imap.example.com, example.com or example.org i bought a cheap SSL Class2 Certificate at startssl.com website. But after updating Postfix configuration replacing the old Godaddy SSL Certificate by the new StartSSL.com SSL Class2 Certificate, email desktop clients complain about the smtp.example.com not being the Common Name example.com.

I've configured `nginx and everything seems to work fine when accessing to any of the following example names and example alternative names:

```
example.com
imap.example.com
smtp.example.com
mail.example.com
*.example.com
example.org
imap.example.org
smtp.example.org
mail.example.org
*.example.org
```

On Postfix i have the following configuration for Godaddy Certificate:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/example.key
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/sf_bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

For StartSSL.com Class2 Certificate i tried the following setup combinations without luck:

Combination1

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/example.key
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Combination2
cat example.crt sub.class2.server.ca.pem >> mycert.crt

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/example.key
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Combination3
cat example.crt sub.class2.server.ca.pem >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/example.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/example.key
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

As i see, the main issue come because clients can't see the alternative names which are located under x509v3 but HTTP browsers like chrome or Firefox do.

Comment: See http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved.

Comment: I can't see how that link is going to help on that issue.

Comment: However, it may help you to write a question which doesn't reference a commercial entity (`domain.com`).

Comment: I've just updated the question  so you can have a better sleeping tonight. Thank you anyway.

Comment: And you did it wrong. The link given to you clearly states that "example.com" or "example.org" are appropriate. "mydomain.com" does not belong to you and you should not use a domain belonging to someone else in your question; it's bad manners and may make it harder for people willing to spend their time helping you.

Comment: I fixed it for you. Unfortunately, that took all the time I had available for your question so I'm unable to help you further. Sorry about that.

Comment: Really a great way to help people. I edited crt and key names to refelct domain names. Hope now no one gets messed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got startssl.com class 2 SSL Certificate working with Postfix 2.11, so my current configuration works fine for multiple domains and subdomains.

Here's the working configuration just in case anyone needs it.

Postfix /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/class2.webeloping_es.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/class2.webeloping_es.key
## This file was download from startssl.com
smtp_tls_CAfile=/etc/ssl/certs/startssl_ca-bundle.pem
smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
```

Courier Imap /etc/courier/imapd-ssl

```
$ cat /root/SSL/startssl.com/class2.webeloping_es.crt /root/SSL/startssl.com/class2.webeloping_es.key >> /etc/ssl/private/startssl-crt_key.pem 

TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/ssl/private/startssl-crt_key.pem
TLS_TRUSTCERTS=/etc/ssl/certs/startssl_ca-bundle.pem
```